# Answer the following i.e, to display category and subcategory from same table

Tags: php, categories

I have one table containing 3 columns i.e, id,categories and subcategories. When i get distinct categories values to a table as table head() using while loop. Then how could i get the subcategories as table data () based in caregory. Can you please answer for this?

Comment: You can use GROUP BY clause while fetching the data.

Comment: Post what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

> you can select all data from data base  and separate category and
>   subcategory in your php script

```
   $categoryAll = findAll(); // Select all from your table 

      $parent = array();

      foreach ($categoryAll as $category) {
        if ($category['parent_id'] == 0) {
          $parent[$category['parent_id']] = array('name' => $category['name']);
        }
      }

      foreach ($categoryAll as $category) {
          if ($category['parent_id'] != 0) {
        $parent[$category['parent_id']]['subCategory'][] = array(
            'name' => category['name']
        );
          }
      }
```

Your all category and sub categoy in your $parent array

```
[1] => Array
(
    [name] => Parent Category
    [subCategory] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => subcategory

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => subcategory

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks...The Below code is also working but, the Result should not able apply with in CSS styles

Comment: include("db.php");

       $category = mysql_query( "Select * FROM cat "); 
       if(!$category) 
       { 
        die( "Data Base Query1 Failed: " . mysql_error()); 
       } 

       while($product=mysql_fetch_array($category))
       {
        $c=$product['category'];
        $i=$product['cid'];
?>


<ul id="nav">
    <?php echo '<li class="parent"><a href="#" >'.$product['category'].'</a>';?>
        <ul>

Comment: <?php
        $subcategory_set = mysql_query( "Select * FROM subcat where category=$i");
        
        while($childproduct=mysql_fetch_array($subcategory_set))
        {
         echo '<li class="parent"><a href="#" >'.$childproduct['subcategory'].'</a>';
         ?>
               
               <?php } ?> 
            </li> 
</ul>
</ul>
<?php } ?>

Comment: Check this array it is array between array .
 
foearch ($category as $cat){
   echo "<li class='parent'>".$cat['name']."</li><ul>"
   foreach($cat['subCategory'] as $subcategory){
 echo "<li>".$subcategory['name']."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
}

use code it will work